# Different test results from memtester vs memtest86

Tags: memory

When I run a memory test with memtest86, or memtest86+, I keep getting errors. I get tens of errors for one test pass. I tested each of the 6 memory sticks I have (4GB) in each slot individually, and I also get errors. I tested the sticks on another PC, and there were no errors.

Therefore, I am certain my sticks are fine. I was suspecting failures of memory controller in the motherboard.

However, my system runs fine, and I am getting zero errors after several passes over most of the memory (8GB out of 12GB).

How is it possible memtester consistently reports zero errors, while memtest86 consistently reports tens of errors? If it were the other way around, I would suspect OS failure, but I am quite confused here.

### Hardware

- Mobo: Gigabyte GA-X58A-UD3R rev. 2.0
- CPU: INTEL Core i7-950

P.S.: I do not have ECC memory. Maybe OS has some ECC capabilities? I am running Linux Debian.

P.P.S.: Whenever memtest86 reports an error, the problem is the actual bits are all zeros, while there should have been some "ones".

Comment: The ISO boot version of Memtest / Memtest86 does not involve your installed OS(es) in any way.  These projects need to do some work to keep current with your motherboard & CPU, as well as having slightly different default test sets.  Please provide your motherboard model, CPU, and which test set options you are picking in each program.

Comment: I added motherboard and CPU info. I am running the default test sets for both memtester and memtest86+ (did not try to tweak any options). I tried running memtest86+ from HDD as it is included in my Linux Debian installation, as well as from usb flashdrive loaded with bootable memtest86 ISO. Both showed errors.